# Chrome extension: onclick() event is not triggering an alert() popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, event-handling, dom-events, google-chrome-app

I am unable to trigger an `alert()` popup with an `onclick()` event.

### Code

### File *manifest.json*

```
{
    "name": "Project",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Popup when website requires Log in",
    "browser_action":{
        "default_icon":"icon_19.png",
        "default_popup":"Popup.html"
        }
}
```

### File *Popup.html*

```
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
    <div class="plus" onclick="popup()"></div>
    <script src="inline.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### File *inline.js*

```
function popup() {
    var link = document.URL;
    alert("This is the link: (" + link + ")");
}
```

Comment: Don't use any inline code, move it all to an external file. That includes the `onclick` as well.

Comment: @BeardFist Thanks a lot . and how can i get the url of the website ? Its just showing the url of the popup.html

Comment: You can use [`chrome.tabs.query`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-query) with `active:true` to get the current tab, then use `tab.url` to get the url.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use inline JavaScript code in a Google Chrome extension.

HTML:

```
<div class="plus"></div>
<script src="inline.js"></script>
```

JavaScript:

```
function popup(e) {
  var link = document.URL;
  alert("This is the link: (" + link + ")");
}

var plusBtn = document.querySelector('.plus');
plusBtn.addEventListener('click', popup);
```