# How do I have my chrome extension read and execute an external JS file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hey I have been trying to create a ' first extension' for quite a few hours following tutorials and blogs but  the problem ive run across is trying to implement Javascript , Ive used a combination of JS and HTML to make webpages and Java for some basic programs but whenever I attempt to make a simple alert tag with the simple hello world text nothing happens , ive played around with it a bit and found out I cannot use  inline jS so I looked at [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15766495/chrome-extension-onclick-event-not-triggering-alert-popup) and attempted to imitate the code presented here and got this :

MANIFEST:

```
      {
"manifest_version" : 2 ,
"name" : " Test" , 
"version" : "1.0",
"description" : " A basic test extension" , 

"icons" : {
"128" : "icon_128.png"
} , 

"background" : {

"scripts" : ["java.js"]

},

"browser_action": {
"default_icon" : "icon_128.png" ,
"default_title" : "Testing" ,
"default_popup" : "popup.html" 

},



"permissions": [
"background",
"tabs",
"http://*/*",
"https://*/*"


]

}
```

POPUP.HTML

```
  <html>
    <head>

     <!--   <script src='java.js'>
      </script> -->




        <!-- 
this went on manifest page

"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*/*"],     
      "js": ["java.js"]

    }
  ],

-->
    </head>
 <body>

    <h2 ><b>WELCOME</b></h2>
    <hr>
<input id="clock" class="clock" value="click" type="button">    

     <p id="p">

     </p>
    </body>


</html>
```

JAVA.JS

```
/*function hello(e){
alert("Hello World");
}


var ClickBtn = document.querySelector('.click');
ClickBtn.addEventListener('click' , hello); 

*/

/*
function hello(e){
alert("Hey");

  }



document.getElementsById("clock").addEventListener("click", hello)

*/
function hello(e){
    var work = "It is working";
console.log(work);



}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(hello)
```

and it's still not working , can anyone help me?

Comment: put the script after the element you want to attach the event to, or use DOMContentLoaded as shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591983/onclick-within-chrome-extension-not-working

Comment: Have you read the documentation of [`chrome.browserAction.onClicked`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#event-onClicked)? "This event will not fire if the browser action has a popup."